# Bypassing Youtube region restrictions

Tags: windows

I am trying to use Tor to access videos with region restriction. When i use the ExitNodes and set the country, the browser and other sites like DNS leak test can see the new ip, but youtube still says the video is not available. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but Youtube is probably blacklisting all TOR exit nodes (which in general are known publicly), for the purpose of geolocked content, since it knows that your location is unknown.

Comment: YouTube doesn't block Tor, it just knows that the location of the exit has nothing to do with the location of the user. So geolocked content isnt available.

Comment: Of course, I meant that. Edited it to make it clearer.